How to rerun MR git lab pipeline when there are new changes pushed to target branch
I am in the process of writing a git lab pipeline in order to check our migration file versions. The script as expected, but there is a slight problem with the trigger. The behaviour I am looking for is if there is an MR from some branch to a develop branch it should run the pipeline job, secondly if there are any changed to the develop branch whilst the MR is still open the job should rerun on every new commit to develop.
My current .gitlab-ci.yml file:
validateMigrationSchemaVerisons:
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script:
    - git fetch origin &> /dev/null
    - git merge origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME --no-commit
    - python rest/validate_schema_migrations.py
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "merged_result"'
      changes:
        - rest/src/main/resources/db/migration/*.sql

forMergeRequest:
  script: echo "Dummy job for merge-request"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

The problem arises when there are some new commits to develop while the existing MRs are still open. Am I looking for something that is not supported or is there actually a way to achieve the task?

You can use $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop" so when the MRs are merged, it will run. Also $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" makes sure that only when the MR is merged to develop, it will run, not triggering manually.
validateMigrationSchemaVerisons:
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script:
    - git fetch origin &> /dev/null
    - git merge origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME --no-commit
    - python rest/validate_schema_migrations.py
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"'
      changes:
        - rest/src/main/resources/db/migration/*.sql

forMergeRequest:
  script: echo "Dummy job for merge-request"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

